# Serialized Radio Button | Do not submit, if radio button is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Below is my code, which serializes the list of radio button, these radio buttons are generated by PHP, and then it is printed on the client side using javascript.

What I need is, 
after I choose all the radio buttons, and when i click on Submit button, I want it to "**check if all the radio buttons are selected in the form**", if even a single/multiple radio buttons are not selected in the form, then i need a **RED colour Star (mandatory symbol) next to each Not selected radio button**

Then pass to another PHP which will save to DB. (this is working)

PHP:

```
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','Uid','Pass','DB');

    $standard1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST["tclass"]));
    $section1 =   mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST["tsection"]));
    $SchoolID1 =   mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST["tschoolid"]));





            $query3="SELECT * FROM euser_student  WHERE  StudCourse='$standard1' and SchoolID='$SchoolID1'and StudentSection='$section1' order by StudentFirstName   ASC";
    $res3=mysqli_query($mysqli, $query3);
    echo '<table border="1">';
    for($i=0; $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3); $i++) {
      $dat3 = $row['StudentFirstName'];
      $dat4 = $row['StudentRegID'];
      // data to ajax to display data in a div
      // we put the student's name in a hidden input
      echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $dat3 . " <input type='hidden' name='student[" . $i . "]' value='" . $dat3 . "'><input type='hidden' name='Reg[" . $i . "]' value='" . $dat4 . "'><input type='hidden' name='schoolid[" . $i . "]' value='" . $SchoolID1 . "'></td>
        <td><input name='present[" . $i . "]' type='radio' value='Present'>Present</td>
        <td><input name='present[" . $i . "]' type='radio' value='Absent'>Absent</td>
        <td><input name='present[" . $i . "]' type='radio' value='Leave'>Leave</td>
      </tr>";
    }



    echo '</table>';
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      // radio buttons and input type Hidden data
      $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'save.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),    // reads the data ...
          success: function(data) {
            alert("data Updated Successfully");
            window.location = 'login.html';

        });
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like jQuery validation plugin. 
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Checkout demo here
http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: Can it Validate the "serialized" Radio Buttons data

Comment: If you mean to validate more than 1 group of radio buttons, yes it can do it

Comment: Let me put my question again to a specific line in my code. The code is  <td><input name='present[" . $i . "]' type='radio' value='Present'>Present</td> here this will generate the list of values and radio buttons dynamically. So the validator should be able to validate "not just the static form, however it should be able to validated the dynamically generated list of radio buttons". Adding this dynamically generated radio buttons list changes again and again based on the conditions.

Comment: Yes the plugin will do this client side validations. Just check examples and implement.